# How to plot two lists in the same graph maintaining the scale of the points?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, complex

I need to plot two lists of complex numbers in the same graph to show some results, so I'm using the following lists to do that:

```
modquaseesc = {-0.8880146641362043` - 
   0.5279941967067215` I,...}

listfreqgrav = {-1.9122901521705156` - 
       0.25201677748289864` I, -2.1321454971037404` - 
       0.27055536524472346` I,...}
```

And the following code to run a combined graph:

```
Show[{Transpose@Through@{Re, Im}@listfreqgrav;  ListPlot[coords, PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium]],    PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"Re(\[Omega])", "Im(\[Omega])"},    PlotMarkers -> "*"], Transpose@Through@{Re, Im}@modquaseesc;  ListPlot[coords, PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium]],   PlotRange -> Automatic,    AxesLabel -> {"Re(\[Omega])", "Im(\[Omega])"},   PlotMarkers -> "\[SmallCircle]"]}]
```

This way I get this Graph out of scale:

[image: Image that I got!]

Compare with the graphs separately, the graphs are different from each other:
[image]

And:

[image]

Then, How could I generate a Graph with both plots saving the scale of each one?

Graciously! Thank you for supporting since now!

Comment: CaN you give more data points? I am unable to see a difference between the graphs.

Comment: So @Jack, they're very large lists, I just provided a minimal example, but I can affirm that they different each other! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made two fake data sets that were similar but not identical.

```
modquaseesc = Table[x + I (Exp[-Abs[x]] - 1), {x, -4, 4, 0.4}];
listfreqgrav = Table[x + I (Exp[-Abs[x + 1.]] - 1), {x, -4, 4, 0.4}]
```

Your code doesn't have `coords` defined. I am quite certain you meant to make that assignment in your first and third statements inside of `Show`. If you make those two assignments your code works fine.

However, I have some suggestions.

1. I would recommend using `With` rather than defining `coords` inside `Show`.
2. Once you define the `AxesLabel` in the first plot, it is not needed in the second plot.
3. If you explicitly assign `PlotMarkers` as text, `PointSize` has no effect. Use `Style` instead.
4. Either set `PlotRange` in the first plot or (better) set it as a command in `Show`.
5. No need to provide `Show` with a list. It is happy with comma separated elements.

   ```
   With[
    {
     coords1 = Transpose@Through@{Re, Im}@listfreqgrav,
     coords2 = Transpose@Through@{Re, Im}@modquaseesc
     },
    Show[
     ListPlot[coords1,
      PlotMarkers -> Style["*", Red, 20],
      AxesLabel -> {"Re(ω)", "Im(ω)"}
      ],
     ListPlot[coords2,
      PlotMarkers -> Style["∘", Green, 20]
      ],
     PlotRange -> All
     ] 
    ]
   ```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

In order to get `PlotLegends` put everything inside a single `ListPlot` and use the labels you desire for the legend.

```
With[
 {
  coords1 = Transpose@Through@{Re, Im}@listfreqgrav, 
  coords2 = Transpose@Through@{Re, Im}@modquaseesc
  },
 ListPlot[{coords1, coords2},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotMarkers -> {Style["*", Red, 20], 
    Style["∘", Green, 20]}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Re(ω)", "Im(ω)"},
  PlotLegends -> {"First", "Second"}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hello @Jack, Thanks a lot for you Answer, It worked really well to me! I've got a graph with  the two lists together, I appreciate your good will In helping us! Thak you again! :D

Comment: How could I insert legends in this graph? :)

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how to make a legend. You can also use `Placed` if you want the legends in a different position.